# Set error label default as false globally

Tags: simple-form

I found a lot of articles describing that we can disable the error label by adding false to the form.

However, it seems that it is still very clumsy to set it one by one.

Therefore, I would like to ask if we can set a default false value in the initialisers to hide the error label, while we can set a true value when we want to use it?